# Is there any way in tensorflow to iterate all the training error during training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, runtime-error, loss-function

I am trying to design a new loss function to iterate all the training errors for each data in a training batch and calculate the new loss base on the magnitude of different errors.
Do there have any way to achieve it? Because when you design the loss function, the error.shape[0] would be None, so the traditional ways may not be used to iterate the errors.

error=Ypred-Ytrue and all of their shape[0] are None, so I don't know how to iterate the errors now. I need to know the errors during training and compare their magnitude with one specific value to know how many errors are larger than it. And then calculate the loss base on it.

In short, I want to calculate the mean error of the errors larger than 0.5 and the mean error smaller than 0.5 in a batch respectively, and then use their addition as the loss function.

Do there has any way can achieve it?

Comment: Maybe you should include what loss you are implementing, as many losses do not require explicit iteration to be implemented in most frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Larger_Error=Error[Error>0.5] can work.

It is a quite silly problem, but still keep this problem for the starters in deep learning just like me :-)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).